# How To Query S3 Objects with CLI instead of S3 Select?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, select-object

I need a CLI alternative similar to the example here in [Dashboard link](https://predictivehacks.com/how-to-query-s3-objects-with-s3-select/) but with Json as input & output serialization types.

I have tried running the following for Json in AWS cloud shell to get the output printed on the terminal,but end up getting an error.

```
aws s3api select-object-content --bucket "my-bucket" --key jobs/test.json --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s LIMIT 5" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization "{"JSON":{"Type": "DOCUMENT"},"CompressionType": "None"}" --output-serialization "{"JSON": {Type: 'DOCUMENT'}}" /dev/stdout
```

**Error:**
Error parsing parameter '--input-serialization': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {JSON:{Type: DOCUMENT},CompressionType: None}

I see a lot of options for csv format ,but unable to find the same for Json.

Thank you in advance.

Note:Running on AWS cloudshell which is basically on Linux.

**FYI:**
The following is the dashboard alternative of the input & output serialization I am trying to achieve here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes `'` to enclose the entire JSON string, if you are using linux/macOS terminal. In powershell, use `\` to escape the double quotes.

like this -

```sh
aws s3api select-object-content --bucket "my-bucket" --key jobs/test.json --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s LIMIT 5" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization '"{"JSON":{"Type": "DOCUMENT"},"CompressionType": "None"}"' --output-serialization '"{"JSON": {Type: "DOCUMENT"}}"' /dev/stdout
```

Note: If you have any single quotes inside your JSON string, needs to be escaped with backslash `\`.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error :(

Comment: Can you try the suggestions given here according to your shell?  
[aws cli quotation marks usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html)

Comment: This command is double quoting the JSON documents, you want `--input-serialization '{"JSON":{"Type": "DOCUMENT"},"CompressionType": "None"}' --output-serialization '{"JSON": {"Type": "DOCUMENT"}}'` (note the lack of quotes around the brackets, and the quotes around the second `Type`

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward @vman . That error is sorted now .. I am trying something with the `--input-serialization '{"JSON":{"Type": "LINES"},"CompressionType": "NONE"}' --output-serialization '{"JSON": {"Type": "LINES"}}' /dev/stdout` 

I am getting the following error. 
"Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in OutputSerialization.JSON: "Type", must be one of: RecordDelimiter"

Added a screenshot to the post what I exactly need in my input/output serialization.
Can you help me validate the same?

Comment: **The final working solution:**

`aws s3api select-object-content --bucket "my-bucket" --key jobs/test.json --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s LIMIT 5" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization '{"JSON":{"Type": "DOCUMENT"},"CompressionType": "NONE"}' --output-serialization '{"JSON":{"RecordDelimiter":"n"}}' /dev/stdout`

Credits to my colleague Amit CS(wish I could tag him here) for figuring out the missing pieces.